# Wireless Network

Tags: ros, wireless, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you need a Wireless Network in order to operate the turlebot, is there anyway to get around this/use the turtlebot with only one computer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38453/wireless-network/) by [OakMan24](https://answers.ros.org/users/2808/oakman24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can reconfigure the TurtleBot to start without a wireless network with the following:

```
roscd turtlebot_bringup/upstart
sudo ./install.bash lo
```

This will have the side-effect of being unable to access the ROS network on the TurtleBot from other computers.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not think there's a need to reconfigure the TurtleBot at all. The turtlebot laptop is connected to the robot with 2 cables (Kinect and Create). As long as the cables are long enough, you can run everything on the laptop. But get ready to spend some time running after the robot (especially when you start the autonomous navigation)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-07-10**:
If the TurtleBot laptop is unable to connect to a wireless network, ROS will not automatically start in the background upon robot power-on. Check out /etc/init/turtlebot.conf on a TurtleBot machine to see what I mean.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-07-10**:
turtlebot.conf just starts the service automatically on bootup. It is equivalent to running "sudo service turtlebot start" at a console as per the turtlebot bringup tutorial. I have tried following the tutorial without any network (or any workstation for that matter) and it works fine.